# Comparing Locale languages which is not included in the Locale class

Tags: java, locale, arabic

Since ARABIC("ar") is not included in the languages defined in the Locale class. When i checked only ENGLISH, FRENCH, GERMAN, ITALIAN, JAPANESE, KOREAN, CHINESE, UK, US etc are defined. Is there other way to compare it without using the "equals("ar")" directly?

```
if(MainClass.getLocale().getLanguage().equals(Locale.FRENCH.getLanguage()))
{
<Condition>
}
else if(MainClass.getLocale().getLanguage().equals("ar"))
{
<Condition>
}
```

Comment: Do you have the locale defined somewhere in your code? If so, I'd recommend using that defined Locale instance: `...equals(ARABIC.getLanguage())`

Comment: @JiriTousek nope. the locale in my code are only defined in the java.util.Locale class. Should i just define additional locale in my code?

Comment: Since that locale is not defined by default, I would do that. It's better than using "ar" as it's obvious it's a locale. In either case make it a constant. If the locale setting is coming from outside your application (user's setting?) there's not much more you can do. If the setting is done in the app, the code setting it to "ar" should use the same constant.